# Windows 10: Assigning Application to Specific Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-desktop

In Windows 10, I like keeping different applications on different desktops like:

- Work items on one
- Browser, messengers on one
- Music, videos on one

Is there a way to ensure that my applications always open in a specific desktop automatically?

Answer (score 14):

Checkout VDesktop for W10 -- [GitHub](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk) | [GHacks Review](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/15/vdesk-virtual-desktops-windows-10/)

> VDesk is a free, open source, program for the Windows 10 operating
>   system that extends a system's virtual desktop functionality.

Example usage:

```
vdesk create
vdesk on:2 noswitch:true run:"D:\myFolder\myProg.exe"
```

Comment: If I have multiple windows of certain programs will this help me keep them in the virtual desktops I put them in? They all go to the 1st vd upon shutdown or restart.

Answer (score 6):

You can't currently do this out of the box. The Task View in Windows 10 is a really lightweight virtual dekstop manager.

You can install applications that will allow you to do this e.g. Dexpot @ http://dexpot.de/ (beware of Malware options when installing).

You could also vote for this on uservoice; if you don't mind waiting for it to be included in a future version: https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/265757-windows-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6589344-true-virtual-desktops.

Comment: User-Voice link is restricted

Comment: It looks like the Windows and Windows Phone user voices have been replaced with feedback applications. http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-uservoice-feedback-site-shut-down-after-nov-6

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple script that uses the microsoft powershell script mentioned by HB and allows you to start a bunch of items in one go (on different desktops)

https://github.com/SuperflyJon/FileStarter

Answer (score 0):

Without software, you can create a .bat file containing a ps1 (powershell script) file location.
If the bat file boots, the ps1 boots.
The ps1 can contain the programs you want to boot.
Their window location 'should' be saved based on their last known window location (and provided, the program shut down correctly)

This site's example.ps1 shows how to create a new desktop environment, and open a program (notepad) in all desktops.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-commands-to-d0e79cc5

Comment: This link goes to a search page. Can you inline the code in your answers?