# Starting Programs in a Specific Virtual Desktop

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, virtual-desktop

When I boot my laptop, I'd like to have two programs open, A and B. I can do this using the startup folder, but I'd like to open A in my first desktop and B in my second desktop. Is this possible in Windows 10? Perhaps there's a solution in batch?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10: Assigning Application to Specific Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/956884/windows-10-assigning-application-to-specific-desktop)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the program [VDesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk) to achieve this functionality.

> [VDesk for Windows 10: launch programs on virtual desktops](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/15/vdesk-virtual-desktops-windows-10/)
>
> Vdesk is a portable program for Windows that adds the feature to
>   Windows 10. It is a command line program but ships with an option to
>   integrate its functionality in File Explorer.
>
> The main command looks like this: `vdesk [n] [command [args]]`
>
> - **n** sets the index of the virtual desktop you want to launch the program on.
> - **[command [args]]** specifies the program and arguments that you want it to start.
>
> The command `vdesk notepad.exe` launches Notepad on a new virtual
>   desktop, while `vdesk 3 notepad c:\text.txt` opens Notepad on virtual
>   desktop 3 and uses an argument to load `text.txt` automatically.
>
> [You can run](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/11/28/how-to-autostart-programs-during-windows-log-on/) the application on start of Windows 10 to always load
>   programs on virtual desktops when the operating system starts by
>   creating simple batch files, and adding them to one of the many
>   [startup locations of the operating system](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/04/windows-automatic-startup-locations/).
>
> The option to launch a program on a new virtual desktop can be added
>   to File Explorer as well. You need to run *vdesk -install* for that on
>   the command line, and will notice afterwards that a new "open in new
>   virtual desktop" option is available when you right-click on
>   executable files in File Explorer.
>
> The command *vdesk -uninstall* removes the entry from File Explorer
>   again.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original answer was posted, VDesk command line syntax has changed, and
the context menu feature (`vdesk -install`) is no longer available.  The
referenced [ghacks.net article](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/15/vdesk-virtual-desktops-windows-10/) has been *partially* updated.  The
[README](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk#vdesk) and usage popup look correct but omit the `vdesk n` command
mentioned in the [1.1.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk/releases/tag/v1.1.0).  I imagine these inconsistencies are
the source of some users' difficulties in getting VDesk to work.

For quick reference, here are the VDesk 1.2.0 command formats which I have found
to work on Windows 10 Home 1903:

`vdesk`                         Show VDesk Usage popup.

`vdesk create`                  Create a new desktop.
`vdesk create:n`                Create new desktop(s) to total *n*.

`vdesk n`                       Switch to desktop number *n*.
`vdesk run:command [args]`      Switch to new desktop, run program.
`vdesk on:n run:command [args]` Switch to desktop *n*, run program.

`vdesk noswitch:true run:command [args]` Run on a new desktop.
`vdesk noswitch:true on:n run:command [args]` Run on desktop *n*.

**Note**: `noswitch:true` opens the application's first window on the specified
desktop.  Any additional windows open on the current desktop.

Commands must specify an executable whose filename is either fully qualified, or
exists in a directory/folder on the PATH.  It can be a script if there is an
associated executable to open it (in some cases I have to include the script's
extension).  If VDesk cannot find the executable, an error popup says "The
system cannot find the file specified".  If the file is not executable, it may
say "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation".