# How can I force a program to open in a specific desktop?

Tags: command-line, windows-10, batch-file, virtual-desktop

I've created an environment where I use 3 different desktop configurations, but every time I reboot, I have to manually open each program in that target desktop to make it look like it did before.

So, I'd like to write a `.bat` file that can get all my programs running in their appropriate desktops. I'm wondering if something like this is possible:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -desktop:2
"C:\Program Files\My\Other\Software.exe" -desktop:3
...etc.
```

Obviously, this example is not real, but I hope there's something similar. I don't care if it's hacky :)

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/961227/starting-programs-in-a-specific-virtual-desktop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10: Assigning Application to Specific Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/956884/windows-10-assigning-application-to-specific-desktop)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the program [VDesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk) to achieve this functionality.

> [VDesk for Windows 10: launch programs on virtual desktops](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/15/vdesk-virtual-desktops-windows-10/)
>
> Vdesk is a portable program for Windows that adds the feature to
>   Windows 10. It is a command line program but ships with an option to
>   integrate its functionality in File Explorer.
>
> The main command looks like this: `vdesk [n] [command [args]]`
>
> - **n** sets the index of the virtual desktop you want to launch the program on.
> - **[command [args]]** specifies the program and arguments that you want it to start.
>
> The command `vdesk notepad.exe` launches Notepad on a new virtual
>   desktop, while `vdesk 3 notepad c:\text.txt` opens Notepad on virtual
>   desktop 3 and uses an argument to load `text.txt` automatically.
>
> [You can run](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/11/28/how-to-autostart-programs-during-windows-log-on/) the application on start of Windows 10 to always load
>   programs on virtual desktops when the operating system starts by
>   creating simple batch files, and adding them to one of the many
>   [startup locations of the operating system](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/04/windows-automatic-startup-locations/).
>
> The option to launch a program on a new virtual desktop can be added
>   to File Explorer as well. You need to run *vdesk -install* for that on
>   the command line, and will notice afterwards that a new "open in new
>   virtual desktop" option is available when you right-click on
>   executable files in File Explorer.
>
> The command *vdesk -uninstall* removes the entry from File Explorer
>   again.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, Windows 10 only have shortcut keys for creating a virtual desktop and switch between virtual desktops and peek inside virtual desktop. I don't think it is possible assign specific programs to specific virtual desktop.