# Starting Discord (app) on a specific Windows 10 virtual desktop

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop, autostart, discord

I've just come across [this question](https://superuser.com/q/961227/163955) which outlined the process of starting an application on a specific virtual desktop. The only issue is, [Discord](https://discordapp.com/) uses a different method of starting, which looks like this: *(copied from the Start Menu shortcut)*

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Discord\Update.exe --processStart Discord.exe
```

When I add the VDesk command into the mix like this:

```
vdesk on:2 noswitch:true run:"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Discord\Update.exe" --processStart Discord.exe
```

Discord opens up the exact same way as if it was launched normally, on the current active virtual desktop. This vdesk command only works if I edit the shortcut, because the "Start in" directory determines what version of the application is actually run, which is currently set to this:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Discord\app-0.0.298
```

I've tried changing the shortcut to this:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Discord\Update.exe --processStart "vdesk on:2 noswitch:true run:Discord.exe"
```

and also tried with the full path to VDesk:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Discord\Update.exe --processStart "C:\Program Files (x86)\VDesk\VDesk.exe on:2 noswitch:true run:Discord.exe"
```

but these last 2 didn't even start the application at all. Running another application (HexChat) that uses a single exe file to start works without issues.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Well, did you try to either start Discord.exe directly or change the brackets to actually include the parameters to the Update.exe?

Comment: @Seth I left the Update.exe in because I imagine I'd lose startup updates of the app. I don't know what brackets you're referring to.

Comment: Sorry, not brackets but quotes. In your second example (`vdesk o ...`) you'd (probably) only start the Update.exe on that display.

Comment: @Seth According to the latest [VDesk readme](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk/blob/7abdc900da2ba42a9f1bd7d58a25fa68b51f3644/README.md) arguments are added after the command. If I include the arguments in the `run:"..."` part I get a message saying "The system cannot find the path specified"