# How to make program show up on a designated virtual display in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, powershell, wmi

So as some of you surely know, in Linux you can open a program directly on a specific display by exporting a variable `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and then starting a program.

Since Windows 10 also incorporates multi-displays (i don't mean second monitor, i mean second display/virtual desktop), can this be done on Windows as well? How do I do that.
I would like to achieve this preferably from command line or Scheduled task.

Powershell, batch, WMI based solutions are welcomed and well appreciated. AUTOit, Gui automation macros - not som much.

Comment: potential duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/956884/windows-10-assigning-application-to-specific-desktop. There is probably no solution