# How to open program on a specified virtual desktop on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-desktop

Is there a command that will let me open a window in another virtual desktop. This question is very similar to this question
[Windows 10: Assigning Application to Specific Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/956884/windows-10-assigning-application-to-specific-desktop). The windows 10 anniversary update has come out recently and added new features that is why I am asking a similar question.

What I want to be able to do is open certain programs at startup on the specified desktops.

```
vdesk -d2 Spotify.exe
vdesk -d1 chrome.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout VDesktop for W10 -- [GitHub](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk)

VDesk is a free, open source, program for the Windows 10 operating system that extends a system's virtual desktop functionality. That didn't exist when the original question your linking to was posted and now are duplicates.

```
vdesk create
vdesk on:2 noswitch:true run:spotify.exe
vdesk on:1 noswitch:true run:chrome.exe
```