# How can I open an app on a specific desktop in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, virtual-desktop

I have set up 4 desktops on Windows 11.

My daily workflow is very consistent, so I'd like to specify the desktop to use for certain apps.

For example:

- Always put Skype and Slack on Desktop 2

I checked [the Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/multiple-desktops-in-windows-11-36f52e38-5b4a-557b-2ff9-e1a60c976434#WindowsVersion=Windows_11) but I couldn't find such a feature.

Basically, I'm trying to do what macOS has supported for several years with Mission Control.  On the Mac, you can right-click an app icon in the dock and specify which desktop to use it on from the contextual menu.

Does this feature exist in Windows itself and I just missed it?  If not, how might I implement such a workflow?  I have about 10 apps that I want to assign a desktop to.

Answer (score 1):

There are some earlier discussions on this topic for Windows 10, for example:

- [How to open program on a specified virtual desktop on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1157906/how-to-open-program-on-a-specified-virtual-desktop-on-windows-10)
- [Windows 10: Assigning Application to Specific Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/956884/windows-10-assigning-application-to-specific-desktop)

It would be interesting to know whether vdesk works on Windows 11.  If so, you could put the command lines in a startup script, or in shortcuts on the Windows desktop, start menu, or custom toolbar menu.

Comment: VDesk does not work on Windows 11 at this time: https://github.com/eksime/VDesk/issues/92