# Default workspace for application on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

does anybody knows is it possible to set default workspace for application when it starts? I want to set application to run on startup and automatically go to second workspace.
**EDIT** workspace - virtual desktop

Comment: what exactly do you mean by workspace? The virtual desktop feature?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/956884/windows-10-assigning-application-to-specific-desktop